# Regular Representation of infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, infinite-groups, algebras

I am aware of the importance of the regular representation of finite groups, but I am curios if there is an analogous notion for infinite groups. How is the regular representation of a infinite group defined? Does it decompose as the sum of all irreducible representations? Can we generalise this to a regular module of an algebra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an abstract infinite group $G$ the definition is the same as in the finite case; over a field $k$ you can always consider the action of the group algebra $k[G]$ on itself by left multiplication (and this generalizes to any ring whatsoever). It is *never* completely reducible if $G$ is infinite; see [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617971/if-g-is-an-infinite-group-then-the-group-ring-rg-is-not-semisimple). Every irreducible representation is (cyclic, hence) a quotient of $k[G]$ but the surjection $k[G] \to V$ need not split; it never splits, for example, if $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

In a positive direction, if $G$ is a compact (Hausdorff) topological group it has a regular representation on $L^2(G)$ where $G$ is equipped with [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure). By the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) this representation decomposes as a (Hilbert space) direct sum of all the irreducible representations of $G$, and as in the finite group case a given representation $V_i$ occurs with multiplicity $\dim V_i$. For example when $G = S^1$ this recovers the (bare bones of the) theory of [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).